# Why are non-flat counterforce braces supposed to work?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, epicondylitis

Why are non-flat  counterforce braces supposed to work, when used for a  lateral or medial epicondylopathy?

I heard the following reasons:

- they increase the blood circulation
- they provide active release
- they decrease the pressure that is put on the damaged part of the tendon, when flexor/extensor muscles are used

Which one(s)  are correct,and is there any more reason why they would work?

---

By non-flat, I mean it has a bump, as illustrated below (image taken from https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B00QY0EFJM/):

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about this subject but from what I can gather from the literature, how counterforce braces work at all is a matter of theory and debate with no clear answer available. So how this specific type works would be speculative.